# I need a way to use C++ library on windows with a javascript program

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, cordova

I have generated three files .dll .lib and .h for a test program.
I tried to use them in another C++ program on Windows and it does work, but I couldn't find a way to use them in a javascript desktop application like Cordova for example. I need a specific mechanism to do that, thanks.

Comment: javascript is sandboxed, so you'll likely need to use IPC techniques or recompile the browser. can you use node+webkit instead of cordova?

Comment: If you want to access native code from a Cordova app, then you will probably need to create a Cordova plugin where you build the connections between your native code and the Javascript world inside of Cordova.  Here's a link to the Cordova Plugin doc: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html.  Whichever Javascript environment you use, you will have to build a connector between the JS in that environment and your native code.

Comment: No I can't because it's a multiplatform application,
I've tried to use cordova plugin builder but the problem is i have to change the sourse code in order to that,
Thank you for replying.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Whenever you make changes to a program, you have to change the source code. That's what programming *is*. Why exactly can't  you use the Cordova plugin builder?

Comment: Because I need to things for windows only and wont run on linux or android, and I need the source code (only C++) to be edited once and be compiled for both platforms without making two different versions of the same source code. because in Cordova you have to add things like this "Platform::String^ EchoPluginRT" for every method you have and this won't work for Android I think. I hope you can now understand me. thanks anyway for your time.